# How to synchronize TI high precision ADC and DAC via SPI?

Tags: adc, spi, dac, dsp, synchronization

I am working with DAC80504EVM and ADS8920BEVM-PKD from TI. I am trying to design a system which uses TMDSEVM6657EVM processor board to communicate with these converters via SPI.

However, I am trying to figure out how to synchronize the converters and I would really appreciate any suggestion or direction in research.

Here are the datasheets:

[ADS8920B ADC - ADS8920BEVM-PKD](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbau270/sbau270.pdf) 
[DAC80504EVM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau735a/slau735a.pdf)
[TMS320C6657 DSP home page](http://www.ti.com/product/TMS320C6657)

Edit:
I am building a system for 3D ultrasonic distance measurement. Three outputs of DAC would drive three transducers, which then transmit three signals. These signals would be received via hydrophone, which then sends signals to ADC. I want to transmit the signals, receive them and process in DSP. I would like to do matched filtering in order to compute time of arrival for every transmitted signal. That is why I am trying to figure out how to synchronize transmission and reception.

Comment: why do you need synchronization?

Comment: I am building a system for 3D ultrasonic distance measurement. Three outputs of DAC would drive three transducers which then transmit three signals. These signals would be received via hydrophone, which then sends signals to ADC. I want to transmit the signals, receive them and process in DSP. I would like to do matched filtering in order to compute time of arrival for every transmitted signal. That is why I am trying to figure out how to synchronize transmission and reception.

Comment: Could you mux the adc to the dac line upon transmision so your adc knows when the dac started and then mux away to your receiver? it would be more convenient if you just had simultanous sampling adc so you could dedicate one channel to monitoring the dac.

Comment: but is the latency and jitter between your spi,adc,and dac actually enough to matter? sound travels slowly

Comment: To be honest, I am trying to understand the system, and I think I don't have enough knowledge about it now, that's why I wanted to get some ideas to get me started. At least so that I know in which way to think.

Comment: hook the dac to the adc. test the jitter and latency as seen by the SPI for both

Comment: How do I mux adc and dac line? 
I have DAC going to unipolar to bipolar board that is then connected to transducers. Hydrophone is connected to single ended to differential board that is connected to ADC.

Comment: You need analog mux IC. The idea is to have your tap your dac into the adc so your adc view the dac output while the transmision occurs. You could connect directly or further down the tranmission chain depending on circuits details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106617/discussion-between-deanna77-and-dknguyen).

Comment: I have not read the datasheets, but generally you will want to pick parts that have hardware features that allow them to be precisely synchronized. Not all ADCs and DACs have such features. SPI is not generally useful for that purpose unless the sync is very crude.

Comment: @DKNguyen You mean I should connect analog output of DAC to input of mux and output of mux to analog input of ADC? what would be the select signal for mux? I am researching your idea.

Comment: Your processor selects the signal for the mux and changes it over when it detects a transmission the ADC.

Comment: ADC and DAC are both running on the same clock. ADC is connected to MISO pin and DAC to MOSI pin. If the latency and jitter were not an issue, I could just connect them to the same CS pin and measure the signals. But if there is the latency then I would have several random ADC samples in between good ones.
I am not sure how would MUXing them be useful. Since SPI is bidirectional, whenever I have SPI transfer I can get one sample in one sample out.

Comment: Therefore, when I come to the transmission line in code, I can simultaneously also receive samples. But, since the useful samples will be delayed, I don't know how to detect which one is useful and which one is not. Could you please clarify a little bit?

Comment: Examine your ADC signal, when you detect a correlation with the transmission that is your start time for when transmit started as far as your ADC is concerned and switch the mux to the receive transducer to catch the echo. Latency doesn't matter. It could even even be an hour.